# Compass Listener error

Tags: css, terminal, sass, compass

I've started using Compass, and it behaves really strange. When I use the `watch` command, it detects changes and rewriting the main CSS file as expected, but it randomly returns an error on some partial files and won't compile them into the main CSS file.

For example: When I change _fonts.scss, it works great. when I change _intro.scss the terminal gives me the following error:

```
modified sass/pages/_intro.scss 
[Listen warning]: Change block raise an exception: undefined method `to_tree' for nil:NilClass
```

It is just a random error, it can happen with any file, and the only thing that solved it was pressing Cmd+C and using the watch again.

Files that were once compiled can now return this listener error, and vice versa.

Why is that? and how do I fix it? It's really slowing down the development to press Cmd+C and start the watch command every 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bug in Compass - see https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1851

Comment: Yep, it seems like general bug